# Android Textview wrap imageview

Tags: android, textview, imageview

What I am trying to do is wrap the textview around the imageview so that way the text isn't just on the left or right side of the image. Is it possible to do this through XML? As it is a popup dialog with a picture, so doing it through code will be a pain as it is multiple images depending on what they click. See picture for example.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Close" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IV1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/IV1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/TV15"
                android:id="@+id/TV15"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dismiss"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IV1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/IV1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout`. Change the order of `ImageView` and `TextView` to set what should come top of the other.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="this is my sample" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want them on top of each other though, see picture I just posted for more example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem, this project might help you https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview